# Flutter User Registration with API connection

Tags: java, android, api, flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating a user Registration with an API. After the connection, the users should be able to register. After i got an error Message when i click on Registration Button (_InternalLinkedHashMap

```
    // SERVER API URL
    var url = 'http://api.pro.freeapi.com/api/people';
    Map<String, String> headers1 = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'fjhdfjdhfjdhfdjfhdjfhdjhdjhfjdhdkjdfhdk'
    };
```

Error Picture Added 
[image: Error Message Here]

Comment: please provide enough code so we can look into it.

Comment: when i get this error i look data model toJson, fromJson constructors and json.decode, json.encode usage.